# how to build table relationships in a firebird database?

Tags: firebird

I am a beginner in Delphi and I have a Firebird database with 2 tables namely `masterlist` and `daily collection`. I used Zeos 7.0.3 to access my Firebird database.

My masterlist contains the following columns:

```
╔══════╦══════╦═════════╦════════╗
║ name ║ date ║ balance ║ status ║
╚══════╩══════╩═════════╩════════╝
```

My daily collection contains the following columns:

```
╔══════╦══════╦═════════╦═════════╗
║ date ║ name ║ payment ║ balance ║
╚══════╩══════╩═════════╩═════════╝
```

I would like to build a relation in which the balance from `masterlist` will be copied to the balance column of the `daily collection`, and when I update the column in the `daily collection` it will also update the content of the `masterlist`.

Hope this will be considered a good question I have tried very hard to make a useful question.

Answer (score 2):

While I'm pretty sure you should redesign your database at first (and probably read something on SQL basics), you can get what you want with triggers :)

This one inserts row into `daily collection` with appropriate balance:

```
CREATE trigger masterlist_ai for masterlist
active after insert position 0
AS
begin
  insert into "daily collection" (  "date",     balance)
                        values (new."date", new.balance);
end
```

And this one updates balance in `masterlist` after updates of `daily collection` (assuming date is the primary key):

```
CREATE trigger "daily_collection_au" for "daily collection"
active after update position 0
AS
begin
  update masterlist
  set balance = new.balance
  where "date" = new."date";
end
```

Comment: Also you can find better names for `"date"` (it's a keyword and you'll have to use quotes everywhere).